# Permission denied when using rename

Tags: php, permissions, rename

On Rpi Buster, I have tried to move files from ~/pi/Documents to /var/www/html/p-files/. Both directories and files are pi:pi owned, but still I get Permission denied in the apache2 error.log
..
rename(/home/pi/Documents/testfil20210307.doc,/var/www/html/p-files/testfil20210307.doc): Permission denied in /var/www/html/asset2021/upload.php on line 51, referer: http://localhost/content/telep.php
..

line 51 through line 53 are
`if(rename("/home/pi/Documents/".$filename, $target_file )) { echo "Filen ". htmlspecialchars(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " blev flyttet til teleprompter."; }else{`

As I see it the permissions should be ok, but apparently they are not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apache generally runs under its own userid, which likely doesn't have write permission to the files it serves under the pi home dir. (Which is generally what you want.)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. You set me on the right track. Adequate use of chown and chmod now makes it possible to move files. Problem solved, most appreciated!